# URL encoding with SharePoint URL and cURL

Tags: linux, url, curl, sharepoint, urlencode

I am new to using `CURL`. I am trying to connect to a `SharePoint` URL and pull the data in the form of `json`. My URL looks like this:

`.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('titles list')/items`

If I give the URL as it is without any encoding, it fails with a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error.

I tried using `-G` and `--data-urlencode` like below:

`curl -v -G -L --ntlm --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' ".../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle" --data-urlencode "('titles list')" -d "/items"`

doing this will convert my URL to `.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle?%28%27titles%20list%27%29&/items`

But it fails with `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` since using `-G` will append to the URL with a `?` and `&` . Putting `?` and `&` to append to the URL will give me a different URL and hence the `404 not found` error.

I have no issues accessing other end points like `../_api/web/lists` since there is no need to encode it I guess.

How do I properly encode my URL and get the data without any errors?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue by directly giving URL with the encoded characters to `cURL` command. Like this:

`curl -v -L --ntlm --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' ".../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle%28%27titles%20List%27%29/items"`

I hope this helps someone. I know I am no expert with linux or `cURL` and any better answers to this are welcome.